# Html Media tags doesn't work at all costs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Trying to get them working took hours. And still nothing. Tried media="xx" and @media. Css doesnt work at all, or only one of them work. I can't see an obvious error, it drives me nuts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="tr">
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="1129.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <ust>MYO</ust>
    <p id="hosgeldiniz">Hoşgeldiniz</p>
</div>

<div id="content">What is Lorem Ipsum?
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        Why do we use it?
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


        Where does it come from?
        Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

        The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>

<div id="footer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I also tried link => media="min-width" etc, but its not working too.

CSS.

```
html body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#header{
width:100%;
height: 10vw;
background-color:gray;
padding-top:40px;
text-align:center;
font-family: "Palatino Linotype", Times, serif;

}
ust{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 3vw;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color:white;
}
#hosgeldiniz{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color:white;
}


#content{
margin-top: 2%;
margin-left: 10%;
padding-right: 15%;
font-size:1.5em;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #content {
        font-size:0.1em;

    }

  }
```

This is mostly code, i should add more details but I am about to fall asleep.
This is mostly code, i should add more details but I am about to fall asleep.
This is mostly code, i should add more details but I am about to fall asleep.
This is mostly code, i should add more details but I am about to fall asleep.
This is mostly code, i should add more details but I am about to fall asleep.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was your CSS filename starts with a number _

If you Google file-naming conventions you'll read something like "*You should only use the letters a-z, numbers 0-9, underscores and hyphens in your CSS file names* ".

BUT - putting a number first isn't something I would do, based on personal experience and reading / listening to other programmers' / developers' stories.

Half way down this web-page there's a note warning about using numbers at the start of a file name >>> https://www.lifewire.com/naming-css-style-sheet-files-3466881

AND - as you can see in the code snippet, I haven't changed anything and your code works just fine.

This answer might be a bit long-winded but I'm trying to make the case for changing your CSS file-name to something alphabetical, then matching that name in your stylesheet link... and seeing if that works for you

```css
html body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#header{
width:100%;
height: 10vw;
background-color:gray;
padding-top:40px;
text-align:center;
font-family: "Palatino Linotype", Times, serif;

}
ust{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 3vw;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color:white;
}
#hosgeldiniz{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color:white;
}


#content{
margin-top: 2%;
margin-left: 10%;
padding-right: 15%;
font-size:1.5em;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #content {
        font-size:0.1em;

    }

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="tr">
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="1129.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <ust>MYO</ust>
    <p id="hosgeldiniz">Hoşgeldiniz</p>
</div>

<div id="content">What is Lorem Ipsum?
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        Why do we use it?
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


        Where does it come from?
        Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

        The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>

<div id="footer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip